# Enhance MediaWiki Search

Tags: mediawiki

I was just wondering if I can enhance the search facility in MediaWiki, like returning a suggested Result Set closest to the Search Key instead of return 0 results page.

For eg. I have created the ff: articles,

```
Guidelines to Database Management
Guidelines to SQL Reporting
```

But when I try to search just by entering ***Guidelines***, instead of showing me or suggesting me something close, it returns 0 results prompting me if I want to create it.

Would it be a little suggestive, can I make it be a little suggestive?

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Search_extensions?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Lucene in place of the default MediaWiki search engine, which merely does MySQL full-text indexing. Lucene not only would solve the above problem, it also would work if you'd mistyped "Guidlines" and ask, "Did you mean 'Guidelines'?"

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MWSearch

Lucene is nontrivial to install, but the results are well worth it.